# How to add Picasa web album service to Apps account

Tags: google-workspace, picasa-web-albums

I just created a Google Apps account (domain name) but only the core services like Gmail, Docs, Calendar, and Sites are activated. However, Photos (Picasa web album) is missing and I don't know how to add it as a service.

Comment: Have you seen [this help page](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=183358)?

Comment: Hi Alex,For some unknown reason, the screen flows do not corresponding to instructions listed in the help page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Head over to `https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/yourdomain/SelectServices` & add from there.

Comment: Hi Sathya, I did try the above link but the only 2 services are available: Google Apps Marketplace and Google App Engine. I could not find Picasa web albums, therefore it is impossible to add.